# Foreign Key error in migration laravel 5.1

Tags: php, foreign-keys, laravel-5.1, mysql-error-1064

I have migrate this code

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('TechnicianGroup', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('description', 64);
        $table->string('token', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('Site', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('token', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('technician', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('username', 50);
        $table->string('password', 255);
        $table->string('email', 255);
        $table->string('mobile', 11);
        $table->string('avatar_url', 256);
        $table->string('job_title', 100);
        $table->integer('site_id');
        $table->foreign('site_id')->references('id')->on('site')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('group_id');
        $table->boolean('is_active');
        $table->string('token', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

When i excute migarate

```
php artisan migrate
```

The result is

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'upport.#sql-a3c_140' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `technician` add constraint technician_site_id_foreign foreign key (`site_id`) referen
>   ces `site` (`id`))
>   [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'upport.#sql-a3c_140' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot use `unsigned()`. If you don't use `unsinged()`, the column will be `int(11)`, but you need `int(10)`.

The `site.id` and `technician.site_id` must be the same type: int(10)

Try this:

```
$table->foreign('site_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('site')->onDelete('cascade');
```